# Enumerations with and without values

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I have an enumeration and a switch statement based on that enum, which looks like this:

```
public enum MyEnum
    {
        VAL1,
        VAL2,
        VAL3,
        ONE = 1,
        TWO = 2
    }
```

and the switch:

```
switch ((MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), input.ToUpper()))
        {
            case MyEnum.VAL1:
                Console.WriteLine("val1");
                break;
            case MyEnum.VAL2:
                Console.WriteLine("val2");
                break;
            case MyEnum.VAL3:
                Console.WriteLine("val3");
                break;
            case MyEnum.ONE:
                Console.WriteLine("1");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("default");
                break;
        }
```

where input is a string.
The problem I have is that I have a compiler error,

> The label 'case 1:' already occurs in the switch statement

I found that moving the 'ONE' element as first in the enumeration resolves the issue, but my question is why this happens?

Comment: `VAL2` and `ONE` are same

Comment: When you run this in the debugger, what is the integer value  of Val1, Val2 & Val3 ?

Comment: @MartinVerjans Obviously OP cannot run this in debugger as it simply won´t compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well because what happens is when you have:

```
public enum MyEnum
    {
        VAL1,
        VAL2,
        VAL3,
        ONE = 1,
        TWO = 2
    }
```

You basically have:

```
public enum MyEnum
    {
        VAL1 = 0,
        VAL2 = 1,
        VAL3 = 2,
        ONE = 1,
        TWO = 2
    }
```

You see where your problem is, now? You need to assign them different values.

Answer (score 1):

`VAL2` will have the value `1` (since it is placed just after `VAL1` which takes the value `0`). This is the same as the value you've set for `ONE`.

The case labels in a `switch` have to be different values: that's therefore not true in your case, so compilation fails.

(If you shuffle things around so `ONE` and `TWO` are at the start, then `VAL2` would have the value `4`, and the problem goes away, as you observe).

Answer (score 1):

Enumerations in C# are just fancy integers. If you don't explicitly state the value for a enum value the compiler automatically assigns one. So when `MyEnum.VAL2` is processed it is assigned the value `1` as it is the second value. Then `MyEnum.ONE` comes around and also takes the value `1` as well. In the switch this causes both `MyEnum.VAL2` and `MyEnum.ONE` to have the value `1` and since a switch may only include a value once, this causes a compiler error. As you already figured out, simply moving the enum values with explicitly stated values to the top solves the issue as the value `1` can then be treated as 'taken'.

Comment: I believe it actually starts at 0 for val1. See other answers

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble I believe you are right, haven't used C# in a few months and Java doesn't have this enum integer wacky magic. I corrected my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new enum, its options are actually numbers. If you don't define a specific numeric value to an enum option, the compiler set it by default in an ascending order (0,1,2,...). this is why VAL1=0, VAL2=1 and VAL3=2. then you set a value to ONE=1 and TWO=2 and so you have to different names to the same option (VAL2=ONE=1 and VAL3=TWO=2).
a simple console application demonstrates it:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4VcS.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken its because Val2 would be 1 as it's the second enum, and they are zero based, and you have defined another one as "1"(One).  So when you move "One" up, it changes the sequence, hence the issue goes away.